# Azure DevOps Server 2022 REST APIs Broken for Environments Approvals

Tags: azure-devops, tfs, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am trying to call the below REST API to list the approvals (using postman), but I am not receiving any response.

```
GET https://{instance}/{collection}/{project}/_apis/pipelines/approvals?api-version=7.0-preview.1
```

Documentation that I'm following: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/approvalsandchecks/approvals/query?view=azure-devops-server-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP

The error I'm getting:

> {
> "$id": "1",
> "innerException": null,
> "message": "Query for approvals failed. A minimum of one query parameter is required.\r\nParameter name: queryParameters",
> "typeName": "System.ArgumentException, mscorlib",
> "typeKey": "ArgumentException",
> "errorCode": 0,
> "eventId": 0 }

The same API when executed against Azure DevOps Services 7.1 - it works..
But fails with Azure DevOps Server 2022 instance.

Comment: yes, there is a problem. I added a request to the developer community https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Approvals-Rest-Api-Query-does-supoprt-l/10573489

Comment: Thanks! Not sure how long it will take for MS to fix...

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce the issue in Azure DevOps Server 2022 with the API [Approvals - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/approvalsandchecks/approvals/get?view=azure-devops-server-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP) (`api-version` of `7.0-preview.1`). The same request to check pipeline  approvals in Azure DevOps Services works all well.

You may vote [this issue](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Approvals-Rest-Api-Query-does-supoprt-l/10573489) created by @ShamraiAleksander in Developer Community. The support engineer will help engage the Product Group to investigate further. Please feel free to **follow** the DC issue and monitor the progress there.

Answer (score 1):

Let's wait for the next release: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/-Approvals-Rest-Api-Query-does-not-suppo/10573489#T-ND10575193

[image]